# Postgres - Copy Command

Tags: postgresql

I have several text files and would like to import their contents into a table.
Each file must be imported as a record in a table (inside just one field).
For this I created the following code:

`create table my_table ("content" text);`

`copy my_table from '/Users/julio/Desktop/my_file.txt';`

I would like the text to be placed in the table exactly as it is in the file, including spaces, tabs, and line breaks.

However when I run the command above, I get the error:

**ERROR: extra data after last expected column**

I realized that the error in question is because of the tab.

Is there any way to escape these characters?

Thank you!

Comment: You might be looking for `pg_read_binary_file` instead. `copy` is meant to fill a table of multiple columns with multiple rows.

Comment: Is that anyway to use pg_read_binary_file with absolute path ?

Comment: No: "*Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed.*" Anyway, are these text files located on the database cluster machine or on the client's machine?

Comment: This is on cluste rmachine file system but not in data specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making a not very elegant solution.

1. I uploaded the file using the command:

**lo_import**

`SELECT lo_import ('/ Users / julio / Desktop / myfile.txt');`

2. I imported it into the table using a **cast** and **lo_get**:

`insert into mytable select convert_from (CAST ((lo_get (1172557)) as bytea), 'latin1');`

3. Delete the file link using **lo_unlink**:

`select lo_unlink (1172557);`

Thats it!

I hope I can help someone with the same problem!

Julio